# how to convert the x-axis accelerator signal into spectrogram in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, signal-processing, spectrogram

my dataset (patient No., time/millisecond, x, y, z, label)

```
1,15,70,39,-970,0
1,31,70,39,-970,0
1,46,60,49,-960,0
1,62,60,49,-960,0
1,78,50,39,-960,0
1,93,50,39,-960,0
.
.
.
```

i am trying to to use the spectrogam for x-axis signal in preprocessing stage to use it then as the input data for a machine learning model instead of using the original raw x-axis data

here is what i tried to do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dt = 0.0005
t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, dt)

data = np.loadtxt("trainingdataset.txt", delimiter=",")
x = data[:]

NFFT = 1024       # the length of the windowing segments
Fs = int(1.0/dt)  # the sampling frequency

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x)
plt.subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900)
plt.show()
```

it gets me the following error

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\hadeer.elziaat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 7221
    Z = 10. * np.log10(spec)
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
```

Comment: does your code work? if so, isn't it what you expected? what do you expect

Comment: No, my code doesn't work

Comment: if it work i expect to get a spectrogram column for each vector (row)

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is your signal and you can assume that your sampling rate is the mean of `time/millisecond`, then probably you can use the `librosa` library to compute the mel-spectrogram using [`librosa.feature.melspectrogram`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html), there's also other utils to compute signal related features.

Comment: its not an audio signal, its an accelerometer sensor signal

Comment: That does not matter. If the accelerometer data is evenly sampled (or reasonably so), then you can use librosa to calculate on it.